# How To Make HTML Form Result Still Inside jQuery Load() Tab Box, Not Redirected To Action Page?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML form saved as **file-001.php** :

```
<form action="file-001.php" method="post" id="select-block" class="general-form">
<input class="clearme" name="Title" value="Title" />
<input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="SAVE" />
</form>
```

this form process submitted variables on the same file. but this file **file-001.php** actually called by jQuery load and located as tab box :

```
$('a.manage-content-link').click(function (e) {
    var self = $(this),
        file = self.siblings('input[name="block-type"]').val();
    file = file.substring(file.length - 3);
    self.next(".manage-content-wrap").find(".manage-content").load("file-001.php");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

but, when I click 'submit' button, this form redirects me to single page that is http://example.com/file-001.php

how to make the 'action' result on still INSIDE the same tab box. not redirected out from the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the form via ajax

Since the form doesn't exist in page when your initial page load code runs, use `on()` method to account for future form.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#select-block', function() {

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action');

    $.post(actionUrl, data, function(response) {
        /* do something when form submittal completed*/            
    })

    return false; /* prevent browser default submit and redirect*/
});
```

API References:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: bro, what you said is a new thing for me... that's why I need to ask you from very basic. let's say the jQuery load() affect on index.php. if user click button on this index.php, a tab box will appear and this tab box will 'load' file-001.php which contains HTML form. now, the question is, you said "You can submit the form via ajax", how? I have this line : <form action="file-001.php"> on the file-001.php. should I remove it and put some 'ajax' stuff there?

Comment: no... the jQuery javascript will submit the form just the way it is written. Nothing else changes. The only difference is you will need to write some code to do something after the submittal is done...don;t know what you want to happen then

Comment: the submit code I gave you will run when user hits the submit button of form

Comment: And your given code up there should be placed inside file-001.php, not in the index.php. Am I right?

Comment: it goes with the other jQuery on main page. You should probably read some tutorials about form submit via ajax

Comment: Ok, i got the picture now... Now I have to think how to process the variables submitted using jQuery. From your code, there's this line : var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action'), means the PHP part inside file-001.php still 'the guy' who process the variables, right? If I just want to 'echo' some text such as 'your changes has been saved', then I have to create jQuery code that able to do it and put it below your line : /* do something when form submittal completed */, am I right so far?

Comment: `action` is simply the url to send the form data to and is the `action` value of your form or `file-001.php`. You can receive data back from `file-001.php` and insert that, or simply do as you suggest and display a message from within the jQuery. Re-emphasizing reading some tutorials about forms and AJAX. Lots available

Answer (score 1):

u can accomplish this using AJAX.

5 ways u can do it:

1. load(): Load HTML From a Remote URL and Inject it into the DOM
2. $.getJSON(): Retrieve JSON from a Remote Location
3. $.getScript(): Load JavaScript from a Remote Location
4. $.get(): Make GET Requests
5. $.post(): Make POST Requests

**Example by using POST:**

```
//  $.post()  
    $("#post").click(function(){  
        $("#result").html(ajax_load);  
        $.post(  
            loadUrl,  
            {language: "php", version: 5},  
            function(responseText){  
                $("#result").html(responseText);  
            },  
            "html"  
        );  
    });
```

**Example Using GET:**

```
//  $.get()  
    $("#get").click(function(){  
        $("#result").html(ajax_load);  
        $.get(  
            loadUrl,  
            {language: "php", version: 5},  
            function(responseText){  
                $("#result").html(responseText);  
            },  
            "html"  
        );  
    });
```

Just used a Div to load the server side content.

"file-001.php actually called by jQuery load and located as tab box" - use a div inside the tab.

Comment: how does any of your code or methods like `$.getScript` apply to OP's form?

Comment: without server, how do u run php code? AJAX is the only way without redirect to another page.

Comment: yes you use AJAX... but can OP use your code to manage his form? Also `$("#result").html(ajax_load);`  won't do any good outside AJAX complete callback

Comment: yes, he can do it: 

        $.ajaxSetup ({  
            cache: false  
        });  
        var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";  
    //  load() functions  
        var loadUrl = "ajax/file-001.php";  
        $("#load_basic").click(function(){  
            $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);  
        });